# cumulocity - OS requirements

Tags: cumulocity

we are planning to install Cumulocity on-premise for a project we are working on. I would like to know if it is possible to install/deploy/run Cumulocity on Windows OS VM?

Many thanks,
P

Comment: Not tried but I see no reason why it should not be possible. Then it may be limited by your licence type (some frameworks check if running on VM and won't work if you have not the right licence, like a floating licence option for example, you should contact them to be sure). Another possibility is just to try with their 30 days trial...

Answer (score 1):

Mikitori's comment about a trial tenant is correct, it's really the easiest way. Otherwise, Cumulocity actually recommends a VM based installation for availability reasons. If you need more information on system requirements and licensing, please give sales@cumulocity.com a shout.